# What is the difference between creating a SharePoint List and creating a SharePoint "Custom List" app?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

Why can I create a SharePoint list from the Site Content page and also create a an app of type "Custom List"? They both create a "Custom List".

What is the underlying difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just two ways to create the same thing. There is no difference.

If you are wondering about the difference between a Custom List and other list types, a Custom List is just a bare-bones list that you can customize by adding columns. However, you can do that to any list so it's not really that different.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So basically SharePoint has an own pre installed "app", that creates a list once that app is installed and nothing else.

Comment: @AlejandroC  No.  Basically Microsoft decided to hop on the "App" bandwagon and start calling their SharePoint lists "Apps", which has led to nothing but confusion.  Anything in SP2010 that was a list (Tasks list, Announcements, Document Library, Custom, etc.), has now been relabeled in SP2013 and beyond as an App.  But it's not.  It's just a list.